# Slider nav abruptly shows up when reaching smaller breakpoints

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, hamburger-menu

I have built a hamburger menu with smooth transition to make it visually appealing. Everything is working fine and I was able to do this with javascript. However, once the browser reaches certain breakpoints where the hamburger menu displays, the slider nav abruptly shows up then closes.

#### CSS code:

````
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: #54976B;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
        width: 30%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;


            li {
                opacity: 0;
            }


    }

    .burger {
        display: block;
    }

} ```

### Then this is my active class so the transform occurs when the hamburger menu is being clicked
``` .nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0);


}
````

#### And this is my JavaScript code:

```
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger')
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links')

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active')
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example please :)

Comment: Here you go friend https://codepen.io/jjxvi/pen/ZEYjJVJ

Answer (score 0):

Your code seem to be working, just `burger` is not really visible on mobile either. Try adding this for tracking it:

```css
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .burger {
    display: block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid red;
  }
}
```

Comment: So the right term to call this is bubbles? I've tried the code unfortunately the problem still occurs...

Comment: In case it opens and closes, it means, that the event is triggered twice, and it can happen if it is bubbling through elements, or assigned twice O_o

Comment: weird enough, in my live server my hamburger menu appears but not in codepen. Anyways, I've tried the new code but unfortunately,  it still does not work. :/

Comment: Now it seems to me, that `burger` is not really visible :)
Try adding to it `width:30px; height:30px; border:1px solid red;` to inside @media, and try clicking the newly appeared square.